# Microsoft SQL Reporting Services conditional formatting OR expression issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been playing with MS Reporting services for the past few weeks in order to automate our "job status" reporting. **I've been asked to highlight cells which are left blank or 0**, so we can pick them up quicker.

Take the "*Enquiry Ref*" columns on the below image. It'll only be any of the following:

- A Reference number
- Blank
- A number 0

[image: Reporting services]

I have tried the following:

```
//This highlights the cells with 0
=IIF(Fields!EnquiryRef.Value = "0", "Yellow", "No Color")

//This highlights the cells which are blank
=IIF(Fields!EnquiryRef.Value = "", "Yellow", "No Color")

//This seems to highlight neither of the two
=IIF(Fields!EnquiryRef.Value = "0" OR Fields!EnquiryRef.Value = "", "Yellow", "No Color")
```

I can't seem to find an expression that covers both 0's and blanks.

Comment: When the value is blank - is it a database NULL or an empty string?

Comment: It comes in the form of an empty string.

Comment: For what it's worth, I literally copied and pasted your expression into a sample report with *EnquiryRef* values `"100"`,`""`,`"0"` and they all worked as expected in my test (although I did get a warning that `“No Color” ... is not a valid BackgroundColor`. So it seems like your expression logic is mostly fine.

Comment: I get the same result as Ian, using your final expression. Clicking on the `No Color` option in the expression editor selects the value `"Transparent"`, but running the report produces the warning that `"Transparent" ... is not a valid background colour` ! Using `"White"` instead gets rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try a switch!

```
=Switch(Fields!Orders.Value < 100, "Red", Fields!Orders.Value < 500, "Green")
```

Just adjust it for your case and it should work fine!

Comment: BEAUTIFUL, such an elegant approach